# Oracle 11g, about ROUND

Tags: oracle11g, rounding

I am rather new to SQL.  I am attempting to write a query where the "date_requested" column would round off to the nearest day, and place the result into a new column. I know the code is not the prettiest, but it gets the job done in another report. I added the code for the ROUND function, but I keep getting an error:  "ORA-0933: SQL Command not properly ended".

```
SELECT "RIT"."RIT_REQUEST_V".*   
FROM "RIT"."RIT_REQUEST_V"  
ROUND(to_date(''DATE_REQUESTED'') "DAY_REQUESTED"
WHERE (("FORM_ID" = 2011) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 2014) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 5007) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 5036) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 5039) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 7007) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10000) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10001) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10005) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10007) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10011) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10020) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10024) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10025) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10029) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10032) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10033) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10034) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10035) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10036) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 10037) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 11011) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 11013) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 11999) 
OR ("FORM_ID" = 36001))
AND (("STATUS" LIKE 'OPEN%')
OR ("STATUS" LIKE 'Open%'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two little errors:

1. you put the calculated column `DAY_REQUESTED` behind the `FROM`
2. a bracket was missing at the end of `ROUND`

Finally you could use `IN` instead of many `OR`'s. That make the code easier to maintain:

```
SELECT "RIT"."RIT_REQUEST_V".*,
        ROUND(to_date(E_DATREQUESTED)) "DAY_REQUESTED"
  FROM "RIT"."RIT_REQUEST_V"
 WHERE FORM_ID IN (2011,2014,5007,5036,5039,7007,10000,
                   10001,10005,10007,10011,10020,10024,
                   10025,10029,10032,10033,10034,10035,
                   10036,10037,11011,11013,11999,36001)   
   AND (("STATUS" LIKE 'OPEN%') OR
        ("STATUS" LIKE 'Open%'));
```

**p.s.** fixed a small typo at `FORM_ID IN`

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, it is appreciated.  I attempted to use the code, and I am getting an "Invalid Character" error. Any ideas for this one? I do not see any errors, except the column name is "DATE_REQUESTED", not "E_DATREQUESTED".